# Scala - Filter data in DF for each ID based on the transactions in another DF

Tags: scala, dataframe, filter, mapreduce

Problem Overview:

1. Dataset 1: Users will have multiple rows associated with some transaction ID
2. Dataset 2: Each user will have a row associated with each transaction IDs in the database
3. What I'd like to do is remove any transaction in Dataset 2 that a user has in Dataset 1.

Example:

Dataset 1:

```
id trans_id
1  a
1  b
1  c
2  c
2  d
2  e
2  f
```

Dataset 2:

```
id trans_id score
1  a        0.3
1  b        0.4
1  c        0.5
1  d        0.1
1  e        0.2
1  f        0.5
2  a        0.1
2  b        0.5
2  c        0.6
2  d        0.8
2  e        0.9
2  f        0.2
```

Final Dataset:

```
id trans_id score
1  d        0.1
1  e        0.2
1  f        0.5
2  a        0.1
2  b        0.5
```

I'm attempting to do this in scala (python is my language of choice) and I'm a little lost. If I was working with just one ID, I could use the `isin` function but I'm not sure how to do this for all of the IDs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way might be to use a `left_anti` join:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (1, "a"), (1, "b"), (1, "c"),
  (2, "c"), (2, "d"), (2, "e"), (2, "f")
).toDF("id", "trans_id")

val df2 = Seq(
  (1, "a", 0.3), (1, "b", 0.4), (1, "c", 0.5), (1, "d", 0.1), (1, "e", 0.2), (1, "f", 0.5),
  (2, "a", 0.1), (2, "b", 0.5), (2, "c", 0.6), (2, "d", 0.8), (2, "e", 0.9), (2, "f", 0.2)
).toDF("id", "trans_id", "score")

df2.join(df1, Seq("id", "trans_id"), "left_anti").show
// +---+--------+-----+
// | id|trans_id|score|
// +---+--------+-----+
// |  1|       d|  0.1|
// |  1|       e|  0.2|
// |  1|       f|  0.5|
// |  2|       a|  0.1|
// |  2|       b|  0.5|
// +---+--------+-----+
```